# XML Parsing and replacing in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

Feel stupid asking this one but have wasted the whole afternoon on it so far and am still nowhere nearer to a solution. I'm automating the rollout of some Jenkins instances and I want to copy the existing jobs.

I am parsing the config.xml files in a perl script and need to replace certain string elements.

I almost got there with XML::Simple but I found that it was losing the data structure which I need for the output. Reading further I found that this is how XML::Simple works. So I've started trying XML::LibXML

A sample input would be:

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
      <parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition>
          <name>environment</name>
          <choices class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList">
            <a class="string-array">
              <string>1</string>
              <string>2</string>
              <string>3</string>
              <string>4</string>
              <string>5</string>
            </a>
          </choices>
        </hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition>
      </parameterDefinitions>
    </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
    <de.pellepelster.jenkins.walldisplay.WallDisplayJobProperty/>
  </properties>
</project>
```

What I am trying to achieve, for example, is to remove all of the `<string>n</string>`  elements and then add in some different ones.

And the code should be relatively simple:

```
my $p           = XML::LibXML->new;
my $d           = $p->parse_string($input);
my $params  = $d->findnodes('/project/properties/hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty/parameterDefinitions/hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition/choices');
```

This returns a nodelist. But I can't seem to manipulate the elements that sit in this list. If I do a

```
print $params->to_literal;
```

Then I can see that I've got the data that I want to manipulate. But I'm struggling to make the next step. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should take a look at [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.39/Twig.pm). It offers everything you need for DOM based XML manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `nodeList` you have a list of [XML::LibXML::Node](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-1.96/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod) objects.  What you want to do is iterate over each node calling the parent node's `removeChild` function passing in the child node.

Here's an example using XML::LibXML:

```
my $params  = $d->findnodes('/project/properties/hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty/parameterDefinitions/hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition/choices/a');
foreach my $node ($params->[0]->childNodes()) {

    $params->[0]->removeChild($node);
}
```

I assumed that the parent node of the  elements will always be named 'a', and that there would only be one node under the 'choices' node.  You can then print out the XML again using `print $d->toString();`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [XML::Twig](https://www.metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) program that will remove the `string` tags under `a`.

```
use v5.10;

my $xml = <<'HERE';
<project>
  <properties>
    <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
      <parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition>
          <name>environment</name>
          <choices class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList">
            <a class="string-array">
              <string>1</string>
              <string>2</string>
              <string>3</string>
              <string>4</string>
              <string>5</string>
            </a>
          </choices>
        </hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition>
      </parameterDefinitions>
    </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
    <de.pellepelster.jenkins.walldisplay.WallDisplayJobProperty/>
  </properties>
</project>
HERE

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(   
    twig_handlers => { 
        a   => sub {
            foreach my $child ( $_->children ) {
                say "Found ", $child->text;
                $child->cut;
                }
            },
      },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    );

$twig->parse( $xml );
$twig->flush;
```

If you want to change the tag name and text, the setup is the same but you change the handler a bit.

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(   
    twig_handlers => { 
        a   => sub {
            foreach my $child ( $_->children ) {
                $child->set_tag( 'new_name' );
                $child->set_text( $child->text ** 2 );
                }
            },
      },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    );
```

Once you decide how you want to walk the DOM, Twig will handle the details to mutate it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give XML::Twig a go in the future.